# Dropping rows of Multiindex dataframe leaves Index object intact

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When I'm working with Multiindex dataframes I'm dealing with an annoying issue where I drop some rows, and then want to loop through the zero-level index, but the dropped indices are still stored in df.index.levels[0]

Here's a reproducible example:

```
#make the multiindex df
arrays = [
    ["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"],
    ["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"],
]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["first", "second"])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,2), columns=['first','second'], index=index)

#drop a row
row_dropped = df.drop('foo')
print(row_dropped.index.levels[0])
```

This results in: `Index(['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], dtype='object', name='first')`

But I want: `Index(['bar', 'baz', 'qux'], dtype='object', name='first')`

Because I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
for zero_level_index in row_dropped.index.levels[0]:
    print(row_dropped.loc[zero_level_index])
```

Is there a way to access the index that does not include dropped values? Or a way to iterate through just on the remaining index values at level zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done for efficiency, you need to use [`remove_unused_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html):

```
row_dropped.index.remove_unused_levels().levels[0]
```

Or [`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html):

```
row_dropped.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
```

Output: `Index(['bar', 'baz', 'qux'], dtype='object', name='first')`

You can get more information on this behavior in the [advanced documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-shown-levels).

> The MultiIndex keeps all the defined levels of an index, even if they
> are not actually used. When slicing an index, you may notice this.
> […]
> This is done to avoid a recomputation of the levels in order to make
> slicing highly performant. If you want to see only the used levels,
> you can use the `get_level_values()` method.
> […]
> To reconstruct the MultiIndex with only the used levels, the
> `remove_unused_levels()` method may be used.

Comment: Thanks so much! remove_unused_levels is exactly what I had in mind, but I should have come up with .unique myself haha